# How to derive a lower bound of a MinMax inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nonlinear-optimization

Let $x_5,\cdots,x_n\in[0,\alpha]\cup[-\pi,\alpha-\pi]$ where $\alpha$ is a fixed angle $\in(0,\pi/2)$.

**The goal**
For a fixed $(A_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq 4,5\leq j\leq n}\in\{-1,+1\}$, verify whether it holds that
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\begin{aligned}
G\big((A_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq 4,5\leq j\leq n}\big):=\min_{x_5,\cdots,x_n\in[0,\alpha]\cap[-\pi,\alpha-\pi]}\max\big\{&\sum_{k=5}^n-A_{1k}\sin x_k+A_{2k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&\sum_{k=5}^nA_{3k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&\sum_{k=5}^nA_{3k}\sin x_k+A_{2k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&\sum_{k=5}^n-A_{1k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha)\big\}>0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**Difficulty:**

The difficulty is that, there are $2^{4(n-4)}$ times of configurations and for each of them, the value $G$ is different. It is not possible to compute each $G$ for each configuration, since the dimension $n$ is general (I don't fix it as any number).

**What I tried:**
I was not able to derive a good lower bound, but it seems dealing its upper bound is easier. I think this might be relevant so  I wrote it below.

The max function $F(x_k;A_{ik})$ is upper bounded by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F(x_k;A_{ik})\leq \sum_{k=5}^n\max\big\{&-A_{1k}\sin x_k+A_{2k} \sin(x_k-\alpha) ,\\
&A_{3k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&A_{3k}\sin x_k+A_{2k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&-A_{1k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha)\big\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
according to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975942/prove-that-max-ab-cd-leq-max-a-c-max-b-d).

Thus we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x_5,\cdots,x_n\in[0,\alpha]\cap[-\pi,\alpha-\pi]}\sum_{k=5}^n\max\big\{&-A_{1k}\sin x_k+A_{2k} \sin(x_k-\alpha) ,\\
&A_{3k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&A_{3k}\sin x_k+A_{2k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&-A_{1k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha)\big\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now we have decoupled the $n-4$ variables.

Now we can split the left-hand side (if I did not make it wrong..)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=5}^n\min_{x_k\in[0,\alpha]\cap[-\pi,\alpha-\pi]}\max\big\{&-A_{1k}\sin x_k+A_{2k} \sin(x_k-\alpha) ,\\
&A_{3k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&A_{3k}\sin x_k+A_{2k}\sin(x_k-\alpha),\\
&-A_{1k}\sin x_k-A_{4k}\sin(x_k-\alpha)\big\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This is easier to deal with, because each term in the summation, we can discussion all senarios where $A_{1k},A_{2k},A_{3k},A_{4k}$ take different values (thus there are 16 senarios in total), and compute the term $\min_{x_k\in[0,\alpha]\cap[-\pi,\alpha-\pi]}\max\{\cdots\}$ exactly.

**My confusion**

(1) Is the upper bounding correct? and how much we lost in this step?

**(2) Would it be possible to derive a lower bound of $G$ which is easier to compute?**